# Discord Bot Using discord-player: Error playing YouTube songs - Extractor Issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js, youtube-api, bots

I'm developing a Discord bot using the discord-player library to play music from YouTube.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { Player } = require('discord-player');
 
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, // Add MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT
  ],
});
 
const player = new Player(client, {
  youtubeKey: 'AIzaSyDjImSQ-3JMrrjG70hS2r4Hp-vO3W70IgQ', // Replace with your YouTube API key
});
 
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});
 
const prefix = '!'; // Command prefix
 
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
 
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if (command === 'play') {
      const query = args.join(' ');
 
      if (!query) {
        message.channel.send('Please provide a valid YouTube URL or search query.');
        return;
      }
 
      const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
      if (!voiceChannel) {
        message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.');
        return;
      }
 
      try {
        const song = await player.play(voiceChannel, query);
        message.channel.send(`Now playing: ${song.name}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error playing the song:', error);
        message.channel.send('An error occurred while playing the song.');
      }
    }
    // Add more command handling here...
  }
});
 
client.login('MTE0ODExNTcwMTg2MTcxNjAwOA.GFXTBm.Y8eCJ6E5fH0S4ySsMyoJMleCp1VmEbfRMJpYJY'); // Replace with your bot token
```

I'm encountering an issue where I receive an error message when attempting to play songs.

```
Error playing the song: ERR_NO_RESULT: No results found for [YouTube URL] (Extractor: N/A).
```

I tried:

1. Library Setup: I followed the documentation and tutorials to set up the `discord-player` library in my Discord bot.
2. YouTube API Key: I generated a YouTube API key and added it to my code where required.
3. Command Execution: I executed the `!play` command with various YouTube URLs and search queries to test the music playback.

I was expecting:

I expected that when I executed the `!play` command with a valid YouTube URL or search query, the bot would successfully play the requested music in the voice channel, however I encountered an `ERR_NO_RESULT` error indicating that no results were found for the provided query.

Comment: script https://pastebin.com/yUMvYEuc

Answer (score 0):

based on the code snippet you have provided, it looks like you are using outdated code from few years ago. Discord Player does not require you to provide API keys. The latest version of discord-player requires you to have extractors loaded, otherwise nothing will work. For this, you need to install `@discord-player/extractor` library, which provides several extractors that allow you to pull metadata from different sources. You then have to load them:

```js
// after declaring player, put the following code
player.extractors.loadDefault();
```

But keep in mind, creating a discord music bot backed by youtube is against the tos. In order to disable youtube, you can use the following method to load the extractors

```
await player.extractors.loadDefault((ext) => ext !== 'YouTubeExtractor');
```

This loads all the extractors except youtube.

You should also refer to the official documentation of this framework: https://discord-player.js.org

I hope that answers your questions.